# Fiware Wirecloud Map Viewer Widget Not Working

Tags: widget, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have download a map viewer widget from fiware marketplace and upload it on wirecloud instance which i launch from my fiware lab account.

Now i am getting below error:

Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

anyone here can help me how to resolve it.your help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your provided logs, I guess you've used the widget without configuring an API key. Google did block unrestricted usage of their app long time ago, this is why such widget has a configuration option for putting your API key.

Bear in mind that Google does limit the free usage of APIs. You can find more information here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

In case you do not want to get restricted to such keys, you could use the OpenLayers map. You can find it at: https://github.com/Wirecloud/ol3-map-widget

---

[old]

Can you please give more information about this error?

Are you using firefox or Chrome? Can you please open the Developer Tools and go to "Console" tab. Then you should reload and wait for errors in console (marked in red). Those might give some clues about the error.

Best regards,
Miguel

Comment: I am using Chrome browser and these are the logs from developer Tools : js?sensor=false:39 Google Maps JavaScript API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error.

Comment: Edited answer according to your logs. I hope it solves your error, but feel free to ask again in case you need something else.